# How to sum the values of one column with respect to a value of another column in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have data like this

```
Year  Population
2016   1000
2016   1200
2017   1400
2017   1500
2018   1600
2018   1600
```

Now I need the data to be unifying the data like this depends upon the year values

```
Year Population
2016  2200
2017  2900
```

Here I don't need the values of 2018. Only I need the sum for 2016 and 2017. How to achieve this?

Comment: `df.groupby('Year').sum()`?

Comment: If you have data in dataframe, you could try this: df.query("Year in ['2016', '2017']").groupby(by="Year").sum()

Answer (score 2):

There are just so many ways to achieve this.

You could do:

```
df.groupby('Year').sum().drop(2018).reset_index()
```

or:

```
df.query('Year != 2018').groupby('Year', as_index=False).sum()
```

output:

```
   Year  Population
0  2016        2200
1  2017        2900
```